# How to filter a cassandra table on a list of partition keys (Spark vs Spark-Cassandra-Connector)

Tags: java, apache-spark, filter, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I have a 16 node cluster where every node has Spark and Cassandra installed. I am using dataframes so to utilize Spark MLlib also. So, I am wondering which of the following methods would be faster and less costly to filter a cassandra table based on a list of partition keys. Specifically, to be able to choose 4827 partition keys which contain ~2 billion rows from a cassandra table.

**Spark offers the**

1. Join method (BroadcastHashJoin)
2. filter.isin (which will pushdown predicates to cassandra, but I think it may put a big load on one node while also there may be missing data depending on the node it hits)

**SCC offers the**

3. DirectJoin method (which for some reason in my case takes more time(~20mins) than BroadcastHashJoin(~7mins) to filter those 4827 partition keys.**)

**I have not used repartionbycassandrareplica with DirectJoin because it gives me an empty dataframe ([asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69676599/spark-cassandra-connector-repartitionbycassandrareplica-returns-empty-rdd-ja)).

Comment: how many rows are in the table overall? DirectJoin doesn't help if it estimates that it won't help due the data size. Frankly speaking, for ML use cases, it's better to dump data as Parquet once and work with them, instead of hitting Cassandra all the time

Comment: It has ~2.2 billion, but it is expected to grow a lot in size, 5 maybe 10 billion rows over time. Hmm, so it is better to stay with broadcastHashJoin I think. I am using directJoinRatio to turn it on and off depending on the number of partition keys being selected everytime. I was just wondering if repartitionbyCassandraReplica could improve those 20mins? But why DirectJoin could not help?

Comment: if you select 2 out of 2.2 billion records, then full scan is more efficient. But you have very bad model - on average your partition is ~400k rows, and it's much more than recommended size.

Comment: I think you are right. According to nodetool tablehistograms keyspace.table I get around 260MB partition size for the 99% on almost every node. The point is, some partitions may have 30.000 rows and others 2 million, I cant know beforehand. Thank you for your comments! However, I dont know if I have understood it correctly..why if I select a big number of partition keys, DirectJoin will take so long comparing to smaller number of partition keys. I thought the SCC converts data into requests to individual partitions or rows that are executed in parallel, which would be faster than a full scan.

Comment: Actually, no - when you have requests to ~90% of your partitions, then connector and Cassandra will need to do more work - find correct partition, find position in it, read next batch, etc. That's why there is a ratio parameter for that. But really, the performance problem arise in too big partitions. As I said, for ML use cases, it would be more efficient to periodically do dumps as Parquet, and work with that - we tested that internally several years ago and performance was much better than reading from Cassandra

Comment: I see, the smaller partitions the better from many aspects. Thank you very much for your comments! They were indeed very helpful!

Comment: @AlexOtt your comments should really be an answer since they're very insightful coming from a contributor of the connector. I've learned so much just from your 3 comments. Cheers!